# Adding Google Analytics to Facebook Aplication

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-analytics

Currently I have a Facebook application and Facebook Insights doesn't give me the data I need. So I added Google Analytics but it shows no traffic. I think the problem comes from Facebook iframe. Does anyone know how can this problem be solved?

P.S. I googled my problem the only solution I was able to find was an image which was generated on some web page, but I don't trust them so I want to write my own code.